# How do I convert dates in Quarter-Year (chr) format to Year-Month (date) format?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I'm trying to convert the dates in my tibble which are currently in a e.g. **March quarter 2001** (characters) format but I'm trying to convert it into a year-month (date) format. The expected output should be 2001-03-01.

There are more than one dates in the tibble so I cannot just reformat that one single March quarter 2001.

I apologise if I'm wording is confusing, I'm trying my best to put my question into words. Can someone help me out?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
separate(col = quarter, into = c('Month', 'drop', 'Year'), sep = ' ') %>%
mutate(dt = paste(Year, Month, '01', sep = '-')) %>%
mutate(Date = as.Date(dt, format = '%Y-%B-%d')) %>%
select(-drop, -dt, -Month, -Year)
```

Explanation:

- `separate` splits the column into three columns to separate out the three words
- make a new column 'dt' with the year, the month and '01' (which will be the day), separated by dashes
- make the Date column from the dt column using `as.Date` and specifying the format as full year, full month name and day separated by dashes
- drop the col that just says 'quarter' and other unneeded columns

Answer (score 0):

Using the input defined in the Note at the end and `as.yearmon` from zoo we can convert the date to a yearmon object and then `as.Date` will use as.Date.yearmon from zoo converting it to a Date object.  frac=1 means use the last day of the month.  The code below gives Date class output which is likely what you want but if you want character class output apply format to the output of the code below, i.e. format(...) where ... is the code below.

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon(x, "%B quarter %Y"), frac = 1)
## [1] "2001-03-31" "2001-06-30" "2001-09-30" "2001-12-31"
```

### Note

```
x <- c("March quarter 2001", "June quarter 2001", "September quarter 2001",
  "December quarter 2001")
```